# Which companies offer good multi-currency bank accounts for the 99%?

Tags: banking

I am currently living in the UK and have savings in GBP, but am just about to move to Europe (Germany). Which companies offer multi-currency (EUR/GBP, other) accounts for people who aren't millionaires?

Criteria:

- Modern iOS app and web site, with English translation
- Call centre I can speak to in English
- Low monthly fees (or better free, if I pay my salary into at least *one* of the accounts)
- Standing orders/giro payments routable in and out via IBAN/BIC **and** Sort Code/Account number (i.e., a UK service provider shouldn't know or care it's an "overseas" account)
- Reasonable spread/fees when transferring between accounts

Answer (score 1):

HSBC is always an option. We use them for our UK-based business account. We opened the account while I still had a UK-based personal account, and there were no issues.

For international transfers, we use Global Webpay (http://www.globalwebpay.com/) - less than five q to move any amount of money.

Comment: HSBC is **never** an option. They are awful on every level. Their website hasn't been updated for twenty years and their app is perversely bad. I refuse to deal with them.

Comment: Also, if you have an HSBC account in one country, they can never help you open a HSBC account in another. I tried it when going US -> UK, and eventually gave up using HSBC entirely for the above reasons...

Answer (score 1):

[Revolut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolut) fits all your criteria:

- Multi-currency bank accounts
- Modern iOS.Android app and web site, with English translation
- Support centre one can write to in English (no call)
- No monthly fees
- Provides IBAN
- Low fees when transferring between currencie

Answer (score 0):

Would [Fineco](https://finecobank.co.uk/public/) fit this purpose?

It's a free account (or 4) in GBP/EUR/USD/CHF if memory serves right. Card in one of GBP/EUR free, other for a small yearly fee. GBP account has sort code and free SEPA transfers can be made from the EUR account.

Exchange rates seemed good, and the site is available in English, plus they speak English.

I think the only thing on your list I cannot cover is the iOS app - I have only used their website. Not sure if it's modern, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since I posted this originally, <strike>TransferWise</strike> [Wise](https://wise.com) have launched multi-currency accounts and debit cards and also fit all my original criteria.